# How to convert string into an array in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to convert the string into an array,
I have tried some steps but not getting the desired result.

```
(:require [clojure.string :as str])

(def stringval "fruit==Mango,fruit==Papaya;veggie==Onion,veggie==Potato")

(defn formatting [strFilters]   
(let [filters (str/split strFilters #";")]
    (for [filter filters]
      (let [eachFilter (str/split filter #",")]
        (for [each eachFilter]
          (let [items (str/split each #"==")]
            items
            )))))) 
(formatting stringval)
```

I am getting below output

```
((["fruit" "Mango"] ["fruit" "Papaya"]) (["veggie" "Onion"] ["veggie" "Potato"]))
```

I want clojure function which returns the below array

```
Array
(
    [fruit] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mango
            [1] => Papaya
        )

    [veggie] => Array
        (
            [0] => Onion
            [1] => Potato
        )

)
```

Comment: Do you mean Java array? So the result should have the same structure as the result of `(to-array-2d [["Mango" "Papaya"] ["Onion" "Potato"]])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a list of maps, so you have to turn your current intermediate
results into a map.  You can do this with `group-by` and some some
post-processing, or you can use `merge-with conj` if you shape the
result from the innermost `for` in preparation for it.  Also note, that
`for` can have `:let` in it.

```clj
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def s "fruit==Mango,fruit==Papaya;veggie==Onion,veggie==Potato")

(for [g (str/split s #";")]
  (apply merge-with into
         (for [kv (str/split g #",")
               :let [[k v] (str/split kv #"==")]]
           {k [v]})))
; → ({"fruit" ["Mango" "Papaya"]} {"veggie" ["Onion" "Potato"]})
```

And in case your target-output there is from PHP or some other language,
that got their basic data structures wrong, and you actually just want
a map with the keys to arrays of values, you just have to to shift the
`merge-with into` out and you can also split for `;` and `,` one swoop.

```clj
(apply merge-with into
       (for [kv (str/split s #"[;,]")
             :let [[k v] (str/split kv #"==")]]
         {k [v]}))
; → {"fruit" ["Mango" "Papaya"], "veggie" ["Onion" "Potato"]}
```

Comment: Note, that just using split will ignore problems when `;`, `,`, and `==`
must be allowed for keys and values and some sort of quoting is used.
Using a proper parser would be the defensive choice.

Answer (score 2):

one more option is to get all the pairs with re-seq and reduce it with grouping:

```
(->> stringval
     (re-seq #"([^,;].+?)==([^,;$]+)")     
     (reduce (fn [acc [_ k v]] (update acc k conj v)) {}))

;;=> {"fruit" ("Papaya" "Mango"), "veggie" ("Potato" "Onion")}
```